# txt2tags and mathmode

Tags: math-mode, conversion

How to create mathmode on txt2tags before convert to LaTeX?

how to make `$\frac{\sqrt x}{x^2}$` on txt2tags and convert to LaTeX?

i search this question on the Google, without sucess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to

http://txt2tags.wordpress.com/2010/11/05/txt2tags-26/

```
 ''$\frac{\sqrt x}{x^2}$''
```

Should work, but this is only marginally on topic for this site.